# mmap() error for UIO Device (uio_pci_generic)

Tags: mmap

I am trying to communicate a custom PCIe device in Linux. I didn't have experience on programming with using system calls and writing linux device drivers.

I loaded uio_pci_generic driver for the device and /dev/uio0 was generated as character device. Then I wrote the following C program to dump 128K data from the device to a file. The device has only BAR0 with size 128K.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MMBLOCK_SIZE (1024*128)
#define PCI_FILE "/dev/uio0"
#define BIN_FILE "dump.bin"

int main() {

    int f;
    FILE * fdumpptr;
    char *ptr;

    printf("PCI FILE: %s\n", PCI_FILE);
    printf("BIN FILE: %s\n", BIN_FILE);

    f = open(PCI_FILE, O_RDWR);

    fdumpptr = fopen("dump.bin","w");

    if(NULL == fdumpptr)
    {
        perror("Can't open BIN FILE");
        return 1;
    }

    if(-1 == f)
    {
        perror("Can't open PCI FILE");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("PCI FILE opened successfully\n");
    }

    ptr = mmap(NULL, MMBLOCK_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, f, 0);

    if (MAP_FAILED == ptr)
    {
        perror("Can't do memory map on PCI FILE");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("memory map succesfull\n");
    }

    if (MMBLOCK_SIZE == fwrite(ptr, 1, MMBLOCK_SIZE, fdumpptr))
    {
        printf("Content dumpped succesffully\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Can't write dump file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However `mmap()` returned `MAP_FAILED`. If I access to device using sysFS by changing `#define PCI_FILE "/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:08:00.0/resource0"` everything works.

So as far as I understood, I could mmap() the /dev/uio0 device but it gives an error. Is it possible to mmap() character device? What would be the problem?

There is no `maps` directory under `/sys/class/uio/ui0/`. Is this a problem indicator?

Comment: Your code looks OK... See anything in `dmesg`? Also, `mmap` sets `errno`, so print it!

Comment: Notihing happens in `dmesg` when I `modprobe` uio_pci_generic, relate my major and  minor number with the driver, run the working or non working code. I also `tail`, `kern.log` but nothing happens. `errno` after failed `mmap` is 22 with `perror()` it says `Invalid argument`. Thank you.

Comment: @emmrk Did you see my previous comment? Any further comments?

Answer (score 0):

The `uio_pci_generic` driver does not include a memory map.

If you still want to do so, you can check section 5 of [this page](https://elinux.org/images/b/b0/Uio080417celfelc08.pdf).

I think that afer you will add this, the map file will be available.

Comment: I added a memory mapping code to the driver compiled it and now I have map directory and it works